# Erro: Incorrect decimal value: ' ' for column 'Valor' at row 1

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, conversão-de-tipo, decimal

Estou com um problema ao inserir um dado de uma `maskedTextBox` no banco de dados MySQL.

Segue o erro

> Incorrect decimal value: ' ' for column 'Valor' at row 1

O código é este:

```
              conexao.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conexao;

                cmd.CommandText = "insert into produto(ProdutoID, ProdutoDescricao, Valor) values (@ProdutoID, @ProdutoDescricao, @Valor)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProdutoID", tb_CodigoProduto.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProdutoDescricao", tb_DescricaoProduto.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Valor",mkd_ValorProduto.Text.Trim());

                int valorRetorno = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: `mkd_ValorProduto` está vazio.

Comment: Não está, eu que tirei o valor, mas é em real por exemplo, fica 123.89

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que a coluna `Valor` seja um tipo numérico e portanto deve ser gravada como número e não como texto da forma que está fazendo então precisa converter o dado em vez de gravar direto. E precisa validar se é possível conversar, seria algo assim:

```
if (!decimal.TryParse(mkd_ValorProduto.Text, out var valor) {
    //tratar o erro aqui
}
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Valor", valor);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/ParseBeforeSaving.cs).

Precisa estar na cultura certa.

Comment: Obrigada, corrigi o erro! Porém, está inserindo no banco de dados com valor 0.00

Comment: Então você continua fazendo errado.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme o usuário Maniero falou, você deve converter o seu valor string '100.5' por exemplo, para um valor flutante para gravar no banco. Ele está gravando 0.00 porque provavelmente a sua função de conversão está retornando 0.00. Faça um debug para saber qual o retorno da função. Confira também se você está tentando inserir com vírgula ou ponto.